# If $G_1,...,G_n$ are groups and $G=\prod_{i=1}^nG_i$, is it true that each $G_i$ is isomorphic to some subgroup of $G$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

If $G_1,...,G_n$ are groups and $G=\prod_{i=1}^nG_i$, is it true that each $G_i$ is isomorphic to some subgroup of $G$? How do you prove this? Inductively? Is there a non-inductive method?

Comment: A rather natural isomorphism between $G_i$ and $\{0\}\times\cdots\times \{0\}\times G_i\times\{0\}\times\cdots\times\{0\}\subset G$ springs to mind, no?

Comment: There is a non inductive methode : define $f_i : G_i \to G$ by $f_i(x)_j = e$ if $j\neq i$, $x$ if $j=i$. Show that this is an injective morphism

Answer (score 2):

It is indeed, and this works for infinite products as well as finite ones.  Suppose $\displaystyle G = \prod_k G_k$ and consider the set $H = \{(e_{G_1}, e_{G_2}, ..., g_j, ..., e_{G_n}, ...) \ | \ g_j \in G_j\}$ where $e_{G_k}$ denotes the identity in $G_k$.  This is to say, consider the set of elements of $G$ where each coordinate is the identity in its respective group *except* for the $j^{\text{th}}$ coordinate, which can be any element of $G_j$.  You can prove that $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, and there's a fairly natural isomorphism between $H$ and $G_j$; I'll leave the details to you.

---

Now, if you *really* wanted to, you can also proceed with strong induction to get the result for finite products.  The base case is trivial: any group $G_1$ is a subgroup of itself.  Then suppose this holds for $\displaystyle \prod_{k=1}^n G_k$ for all $1 \leq k \leq n$.  For the induction step, we consider $\displaystyle G = \prod_{k=1}^{n+1} G_k$.  If you want to show $G_j$ is a subgroup of $G$ for some $1 \leq j \leq n\!+\!1$, first recognize the isomorphism $\displaystyle G \cong \left( \prod_{k \neq j} G_k \right) \times G_j$ (rearranging the order of the product doesn't change the isomorphism class to which $G$ belongs; this is a generalization of the fact that $A \times B \cong B \times A$).  Given that we have now written $G$ as a product of two groups, use the induction hypothesis to finish up.

Comment: Can you please help me with the details? That's where I have the biggest problems

Comment: I added a section about an inductive method.  But, IMO, the first part is the most obvious way to go.  First, work on proving $H$ is a subgroup.  If you need to, try working with a product of two groups first so you don't have as much ink to grapple with.  So suppose we have $G = G_1 \times G_2$ and we want to prove that $G_2 \leq G$.  To do this, I'm suggesting to consider the set $H = \{(e_{G_1}, g_i) \ | \ g_i \in G_2 \}$.  We need to show that $H$ is closed under the group operation and contains an identity.

Comment: Looking at how the operation is defined in a direct product, what is $(e_{G_1}, g_n) \cdot (e_{G_1}, g_m)$?  Is it an element of $H$?  And given some element $(e_{G_1}, g_n) \in H$, does there exist another $(e_{G_1}, g_k) \in H$ so that $(e_{G_1}, g_n) \cdot (e_{G_1}, g_k) = e_G$?  Bear in mind that the possible elements for that second coordinate come from $G_2$.  Because $G_2$ is *itself* a group, the elements that one finds in the second coordinate all have inverses in $G_2$, and multiplying any two of them will give a third element in $G_2$.

Comment: In the last sentence of my first reply, I meant to say: "We need to show that $H$ is closed under the group operation and every element of $H$ has an inverse", though we do also need to note that $H$ contains the identity on $G$, which is simply $(e_{G_1}, e_{G_2})$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $G$ be the product of groups $G_i$, $i\in I$, which by definition means

> There exist homomorphisms $\pi_i\colon G\to G_i$ such that for every group $X$ and family of homomorphisms $f_i\colon X\to G_i$, there exists one and only one homomorphism $h\colon X\to G$ such that $f_i=\pi_i\circ h$ for all $i$.

Note that a priori this gives us only $G\to G_i$, not the desired $G_i\to G$.
But this universal property gives us a recipe, how to obtain a homomorphism $G_j\to G$: We let $X=G_j$, find a nice family of homomorphisms $f_i\colon G_j\to G_i$ and then obtain our $h\colon G_j\to G$.

What $f_i$ can we pick? For $i\ne j$, the only apparent choice is the zero homomorphism. And for $i=j$ the only apparent non-trivial choice is the identity. So let's indeed pick $f_i=0$ for $i\ne j$ and $f_j=\operatorname{id}_{G_j}$. Then by definition, the resulting homomorphism $h\colon G_j\to G$ has the property $\pi_j\circ h=f_j=\operatorname{id}_{G_j}$. In particular, $h$ is injective and allows us to view $G_j$ as subgroup of $G$.